# aws s3 in boto3 - how to move to next page by paginator of s3 in boto3

Tags: html, amazon-s3, boto3, paginator

i'm trying to get s3 objects by paginator or buckets.objects.all(). 
but there were no any idea to pass next page or next token to move.

I would like to show s3 images in html with pagination.

this is s3 paginator code. here was no any passing next page.

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/paginators.html

```
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects')
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket='my-bucket',
                                   PaginationConfig={'MaxItems': 10})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(update, I remove the previous contents, which only apply to typical list_objects, not paginator)

Compliment to @HelloV, if you need precise pagination control , you can try boto3.client('s3').list_objects_v2 instead of list_objects,

Currently, paginator('list_objects') will return a "Marker" element, which allow you to use JMESPpath jump to specific iterators.

```
filtered_iterator = page_iterator.search("Contents[?Marker = `<a_marker_key>`]")
for key_data in filtered_iterator:
    print(key_data)
```

However, you still need to loop through the whole paginator iterator to store the marker key, and do the page manipulation.  For list_objects_v2, you will get "ContinuationToken" (like Marker) and "NextContinuationToken", which let you traverse the page better compare to list_object

Comment: thanks for comments. on as you commented, there was "NextToken". but why in my code with print(response), not exists ?

Comment: @user1429883  After checking the result, I think I make a mistake here, that need some correction.

Comment: that's great answer. "list_objects_v2" is perfect. I can make page UI by "ContinuationToken" and "NextcontinuationToken". thank you so much mootmoot.

Comment: @user1429883 would you like to show an example on how you served continuationtoken and nextcontinuation token ? Also exploring how pagination with boto works, to make something similar to offset and limit in sql.

Comment: @mootmoot if i am on the third page of the list, how can i get back to second page? Do i need to save token for each page?

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing `MaxItems` with `PageSize`.

**MaxItems**

> Limits the maximum number of **total returned items** returned while
>   paginating.

**PageSize**

> Controls the number of **items returned per page** of each result.

No need to track the next page/token, the iterator will do it for you. The following code returns 2 objects per page subject to a maximum of 10 objects which means there can be a maximum of 5 iterations. Both `MaxItems` and `PageSize` are optional. Is it clear now?

```
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects')
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket='my-bucket',
                                   PaginationConfig={'PageSize': 2, 'MaxItems': 10})
for page in page_iterator:
  print(page['Contents'])
```

Comment: ok I didn't know that one was relevant to iterations. thank you. but my case was if user pass ?page=2 on http GET method. or pass ?nexttoken=sdlfkj received from servers. how to control paginator. like mysql has offset and limit. so can control the limitation by request params.